# SQL Server grabbing shared lock while exist xlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

According to this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx)

> Shared (S) - Used for operations that do not change or update data (read-only operations), such as a SELECT statement.

and according to this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx)

> While an exclusive (X) lock is held, no other transaction can acquire a lock of any kind (shared, update, or exclusive) on that resource until the exclusive (X) lock is released.

So, in first session I run the following code:

```
begin tran

select * 
from SomeTable with (xlock)

waitFor delay '00:00:05'

commit tran
```

and while the first transaction runs I run the following code in a second session:

```
begin tran

select * from SomeTable

commit tran
```

And I see result of select statement immediately .

Why does the second transaction not wait for the xlock to be released?

Comment: Experiment with `tablock`, `rowlock`, `paglock`, `holdlock` hints - behavior will differ. `IX` lock is compatible with `IS` so both transactions (with honts you provided) can successfully put these locks at list on the table itself. If no escalation occurs - no need to put `X` and `S` lock on the whole table. First transaction does put `X` lock on keys but check out @MartinSmith reply

Comment: If you ran an update it should block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting answer posted by Martin Smith, but in described particular case there is no sql server optimization. The reason why second transaction doesn't try to grab shared lock is that `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option is ON and in this case the database engine uses row versioning, instead of using locks to protect the data.

If I add `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` table hint to select statement in second transaction OR swich off the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` setting, the second transaction tries to grab shared lock and gets blocked by first transaction.

Answer (score 5):

The X lock *is* held until the end of the first transaction.

However if a page has no uncommitted changes SQL Server can skip taking S locks so the second transaction never gets blocked by the first transaction.

This exact scenario is looked at in detail here [The Case of the Missing Shared Locks](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2010/11/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.html)

Comment: So in a Select - Modify (Possible) - Update scenario, using UPDLOCK is the only correct choice ?